# Conjugacy Classes for $S_{3}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I just have a quick question about $S_{3}$. I keep getting $O_{(123)}=\left \{ (123),(132),(213) \right \}$ yet the answer is $\left \{ (123),(132) \right \}$. Is $(132)(123)(132)^{-1}=(312)=(213)$?

Comment: Note that $(1\ \ 3\ \ 2)=(2\ \ 1\ \ 3)$.

Comment: It might help you to enumerate the elements of $S_3$ - there are six, including the identity. Also notice that in the symmetric groups, elements with the same cycle type are in the same conjugacy class. Now if $a$ is a $3-$cycle so its $a^2=a^{-1}$ so $3-$cycles (indeed elements of order $3$) come in pairs. Since they are all in the same conjugacy class, the number of elements in the class must be even, so you have either missed one or got an extra one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did is correct but with a slight mistake: $(132) = (213)$ so you have written the same element twice.

Comment: I see, is this because $(132)(132) = (213)$?

Comment: No. It is because $(132)$ sends $1 \to 2$, $3 \to 1$, $2 \to 3$. But $(213)$ also sends $2 \to 3$, $1 \to 2$, $3 \to 1$. So they are the same cycles actually.